# Nginx Simple rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I want to make the following url in nginx

```
comments.php?id=34
```

becomes

```
/comments/34
/comments/34/
```

I am trying with this and it works

```
rewrite  ^/comments/$id/(.*)$  /comments.php?id=$1?  last;
```

My Question is, **how to do I force redirect comments.php?id=x to /comments/id**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rewrite ^/comments.php$ /comments/$arg_id? permanent;
```

Comment: Changed this to the answer as more up to date and an overall better solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule), "rewrite operates only on path, not parameters."

Try this instead:

```
if ($args ~ id=(.+)){
  rewrite comments\.php /comments/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain please. You mean add this along side my rewrite.

Comment: That's just a suggestion; as originally posted, it will rewrite ANY request with a ?id=X parameter to `/comments/X`. Replacing the ^ with `comments.php` should get you what you're after (I'll edit to show that). You'll need to figure out how that fits with your `/comments/$id/$userid` requests - order of rewrites will matter, but it looks to me like you have an ambiguous URL pattern.

Comment: Put another way: the `rewrite` directive only sees the part of the request which comes *before* the `?`. You'll need to use `if` blocks to test the parameters.

Comment: what do you mean "Replacing the ^ with comments.php"

Comment: The original rewrite command (from the documentation, as linked) was `rewrite ^ /comments/$1 last` which rewrites ALL urls which match the `if` statement. So I replaced the `^` in that string with `comments\.php`, so it would only rewrite urls including `comments.php`.

Comment: Does not work within location or with server command, all of this code. I am just currently using the one above without redirection.